# How to serialize a django model using serpy package

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize the default User model using the serpy package but no success.

Serializers

```
class GroupSerializer(serpy.Serializer):
   id = serpy.IntField(required=True)
   name = serpy.StrField(required=True)

class UserSerializer(serpy.Serializer):
   id = serpy.IntField(required=True)
   email = serpy.StrField(required=True)
   username = serpy.StrField(required=True)
   groups = GroupSerializer(many=True, attr="groups.all", call=True)
```

I use model viewsets for both serializers; like so

```
class UserViewset(...):
   queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
   serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I followed this Github issue https://github.com/clarkduvall/serpy/issues/17 and now I get **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'**.

I then tried

```
class UserSerializer (..):
   id = serpy.MethodField()

   def get_id(self, user):
      return user.id
```

Yet same error!
It seems the user object isn't properly gotten.
The same error for the groups.

I've tried dropping the required=True, but nothing.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error?